# how to define a unique constraint depending on column value in postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a transaction table defined as follows:

```
mtransactions = Table("mtransactions", metadata,
                    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column("type", String, default='Reg'),
                    Column("cust_id", Integer, ForeignKey("b_customers.id")),
                    Column("date", Date,
                           default=datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()),
                 UniqueConstraint('cust_id','date', name='cust_date_tran'))
```

there are only 2 types of transactions. For type='1', I would like to have the unique constraint as above i.e cust_id, date. But for transactions of type '2', there can be more than 1 type of transactions for the same date. How do I define such a constraint? Using only sqlalchemy core 1.0.8, python 2.7, postgresql 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have [functional unique indices](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#partial-indexes):

```
Index("ix_transaction_type_1", mtransactions.c.cust_id, mtransactions.c.date, postgresql_where=mtransactions.c.type = "1")
```